# AnyChart Background Color While Loading

Tags: java, android, charts, background-color, anychart

I am using AnyChart API for my **android app**:

[Github](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android)

I can't figure out how to set up the background color while the chart is building. I tried all of the different background setting but none resolved my problem. Everytime the chart is loading data I have a white blank space for about 1-2 sec.

Examples with white space:
[Chart 1](http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=ee3fdf-1523906826.png),
[Chart 2](http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=1efbf3-1523906961.png)

After view seconds:
[Chart 1](http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=edfb65-1523907012.png),
[Chart 2](http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=0d73ec-1523907186.png)

I hope someone knows the solution or at least if that is even possible to change it.

Answer (score 1):

We took into account your issue and have prepared an update of the library. Please, download the latest version of the library. Now you can fill the background with a color until the chart rendered like this:

`anyChartView.setBackgroundColor("black"); // or "#000000"`

Also, you can show a progress bar of rendering the chart like this:

`ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
anyChartView.setProgressBar(progressBar);`

You can set your own view with your custom bar.

Comment: Thanks for your help but my problem is still existing. I have donwloaded the latest dependency: 0.1.9 and set the background color like you said but the white space still appears. The only difference is now i get the black one between of them, i took a gif of that situation every time the chart is getting created: https://media.giphy.com/media/1ppURTd5vH7blDNAAO/giphy.gif

Comment: thank you for the GIFю we've just updated the repo up to 0.2.0 version and probably this update will solve your issue. Please, try the latest version and let us know about the result.

Comment: YES!, it really solved it. You guys are great. Thank you.