# AnyChart doesn't display progressbar

Tags: android, progress-bar, anychart

Toolbar doesn't load before the chart!

After referring to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49893781/9025311)

```
AnyChartView anyChartView = x.findViewById(R.id.any_chart_view);
    pbar = x.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    anyChartView.setProgressBar(pbar);
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    final TagCloud tagCloud = AnyChart.tagCloud();

    tagCloud.setTitle("Programming statisctics");

    OrdinalColor ordinalColor = new OrdinalColor();
    ordinalColor.setColors(new String[] {
            "#26959f", "#f18126", "#3b8ad8", "#60727b", "#e24b26"
    });
    tagCloud.setColorScale(ordinalColor);
    tagCloud.setAngles(new Double[] {-90d, 0d, 90d});

    tagCloud.getColorRange().setEnabled(true);
    tagCloud.getColorRange().setColorLineSize(15d);
   final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1383220000);
    list.add(1383220000);
    list.add(1316000000);
    list.add(324982000);
    list.add(263510000);
    db.collection("jobs")...
    anyChartView.setChart(tagCloud);
```

From what I have tried: the progress bar type doesn't matter,nor does if I set the `View.Visible`.

I am using `TagCloud tagCloud = AnyChart.tagCloud();`
Update:Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dell.ora.ChartFragment">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <com.anychart.anychart.AnyChartView
    android:id="@+id/any_chart_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </com.anychart.anychart.AnyChartView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If anyone has encountered this problem,please share how you solved it!

Comment: Can you please elaborate your issue? The issue related to the toolbar or progress bar? Also, do you render it in activity or fragment area?

Comment: I have already defined that it is a progressbar,I render it in my fragment

Comment: Can you provide us code of creating and adjust progress bar, please? We didn't succeed to reproduce this issue in fragment/activity, it works in both.

Comment: I simply create it with the code above and it doesnt seem to wrok.even if I start it it doesnt load,please can you give me an example where you used it?@AnyChartSupport

Comment: Here is a sample of such functionality, please, check it by the following link - https://gist.github.com/ArsenyMalkov/161252fc57cf5c4e5dc68dc00f3ae478

Comment: that's exactly how I have done it

Comment: Please, try to create brand new proect and repeat our approach. Or can you share with us your project (as a repo on Git) to review the code? This approach should work, there's something we can't see or we can't guess about. Also, can you place the bar on layout and do not attach to the anyChartView just to make sure that it exists. Probably the bar is placed behind views.

Comment: @AnyChartSupport I added full code

Comment: Please, check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, the progressBar is rendered under anyChartView. All you need is to change the order of elements. Please, try the following code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.dell.ora.ChartFragment">

    <com.anychart.anychart.AnyChartView
        android:id="@+id/any_chart_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

  <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I cloned anychart from git but it doesn't work. I don't even see a single graph.